# Sharing a file between a persistent and a non persistent Docker Container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cookiecutter-django, caprover

I'm using [Caprover](https://caprover.com/) with Docker to run a Django project ([Django-Cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) which is non persistent. I'm also running a persistent app on the same server which imports csv data. I need the two apps to basically share a file together. This is how i imagined it:

1. The importer app imports csv data and stores it as a json file inside a specific folder.
2. The Django app accesses the json file in that folder and uses a script i wrote to import the json into the database.
   I'm struggling to understand how i can access the folder inside my importer app containing the json file from my django app. Does anyone have an idea on how i can make this happen between those two docker containers?

Comment: Can the importer application accept an HTTP POST request, and directly write to the database, without involving a file at either end of the process?  That'd be much easier to set up in containers.

Comment: I like your idea but that is not a possibility. The importer which is written in Go only allows the creation of a json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share a directory or file between the two containers by [mounting](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) the same directory in both containers.  Here's a simple docker-compose example where two containers mount the same directory.  Then the first container writes to a file and the second container reads from it.

#### Example

```
version: '3'

services:
  writer:
    image: alpine
    command:
      [
        "sh",
        "-c",
        "echo hello from writer >/shared-writer/hello.txt"
      ]
    volumes:
      - .:/shared-writer
  reader:
    image: alpine
    depends_on:
      - writer
    command: [ "cat", "/shared-reader/hello.txt" ]
    volumes:
      - .:/shared-reader
```

Notice:

- They both mount the current directory.
- The first container writes to a file inside the mounted volume.
- The second container reads from same file inside the mounted volume.
- The containers use different mount points (`/shared-writer` and `/shared-reader`) to demonstrate that the same directory from your host can be mounted in different locations in the containers.

##### Output

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting shared-mount-example_writer_1 ... done
Starting shared-mount-example_reader_1 ... done
Attaching to shared-mount-example_writer_1, shared-mount-example_reader_1
reader_1  | hello from writer
shared-mount-example_writer_1 exited with code 0
shared-mount-example_reader_1 exited with code 0
```